# How to verify a form is empty ? PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Please, I'm a newbie in PHP, and created my web site, with a text form, i can verify with JQuery if the txt form is empty or not with the following code :

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#formLike').ajaxForm({                       
                target:         '#content',
                beforeSubmit:   validateForm
        }); 

        //hide error containers
        $("#txtform_error").hide();

    });

    function validateForm()
    {
        $("#txtform_error").empty().hide();

        var txtform         = $("#txtform").val();
        var errors              = 0;

        if (txtform == null || txtform == ''  || txtform == ' ')
        {
            $("#txtform_error").show().append("Please Write a Message Before Clicking : Like It");
            document.formLike.txtform.focus();
        }
        else
        {
        document.formLike.submit();
        }


    }
```

How to verify that the txt form is not empty, and there is not only white-spaces in the field, because here after submitting many white-spaces, the text is posted to the action page.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace this line**

```
if (txtform == null || txtform == ''  || txtform == ' ')
```

**With this line**

```
if ($.trim(txtform) == "")
```

`$.trim` removes unnecessary spaces so it will get trimmed to "" if someone enters only white space.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

for the checking:

```
if (txtform == null || txtform == ''  || txtform == ' ')
```

must be

```
if (!txtform || txtform.replace(/\s/g, '') == '')
```

or

```
if (!txtform || !txtform.replace(/\s/g, ''))
```

or

```
if (!txtform || !jQuery.trim(txtform)) //trimmed only
```

This means, that the input must contain atleast 1 non-space character

Comment: It might be better to use `if(! /\S/.match(txtform))` for the second check, instead of doing a replace operation.

Comment: I've removed the first part of your answer, since val() is actually **correct**.

Comment: replace and match method not working, the Google Chrome JS console return : Uncaught TypeError: Object /\S/ has no method 'match'

Comment: Your function removes all spaces, not only the leading and trailing one. The following should be used instead: `if(txtform.replace(/^\s+/g, "").replace(/\s+$/g) == '')` (`.val()` always returns a string, so checking for null is silly)

Comment: that's what already jQuery.trim(str) does. The remove all spaces is ok since if there are no non-space character in the input, the result will be true. so if we say, "  a  a " = false. "a   a" = false. "  a  " = false. " " = true. "          " = true. "" = true